# Как записать несколько строк в файл на Windows?

Tags: windows, golang

Как записать несколько строк в файл? Почему-то все функции игнорируют '\n'.
Например:

```golang
package main
    import (
        "os"
    ) 
    func main() {
        file, _ := os.Create("A.txt")
        file.WriteString("AAA\nBBB")
    }
```

Этот код записывает в файл «A.txt» `AAABBB`.

Comment: Вы не на Windows ли?

Comment: @Ainar-G На Windows.

Comment: Ну дык у вас `\r\n` надо делать.

Comment: @Ainar-G Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На ОС *Windows,* в отличие от Unix-подобных систем, для перевода строки используется сочетание CR-LF, оно же `\r\n`. См. [таблицу](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).